# get first 4 characters from a console.Writeline result c#

Tags: c#

I am sending a command to the CMD window with WriteLine and I want to use the output that results from that to set the value of a variable. Any suggestions welcome. Thanks

```
var ping new Ping();
string ip = "192.168.58.6";
var reply =ping.Send(ip);

if (reply.Status == IPSstatus.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Nas is Pingable");
    Console.WriteLine("Starting TSM install 8)");
    string HostType = Console.WriteLine("hostname");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    LanuchCommandLineApp();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not able to ping Nas Server");
    Console.WriteLine("exit");
}
```

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Your code does not compile. Also, there are 5 `Console.WriteLine()` calls. Which one is the one where you want to get the first 4 characters from?

Comment: I did not add the full code only the part i am  having issue with, the string HostType = Console.WriteLine("hostname"); is Wrong, But I do not know how to make that work.  I want to get the 4 characters from the results of the writeline("hostname");

Comment: Well, `Console.WriteLine("hostname")` writes `hostname`. The first 4 characters of `hostname` are `"hostname".Substring(0,4)` which writes `host`. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use `ProcessInfo.RedirectStandartOutput` to redirect the output from the console.Then you will have to use `Process.StandardOutput` to read from the output and then take its substring.

You can refer to [this example [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

Comment: When I send console.writeline("hostname");  the results in cmd is the servers host name is returned. The first 4 characters of the return value of sending "hostname" to the console is what i am needing to assign to a varable because the first 4 characters decided what type of server it is.

Comment: Thanks Guys betwen Greg's response and Thomas response I was able to make it work.!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile because you lack an equal sign, when building your `Ping()`.  You should have the line: `var ping = new Ping();`.  You don't mention which `Console.WriteLine();` you want parsed, so I'll assume Host Name.

You would want to more than likely read said input, not write.  But to address your question, how do you obtain the first four characters and remove the rest:

```
var example = "Hello, how are you?";
var filter = example.Substring(0, 5);
// Output: Hello
```

The `Substring` will start at index `0` then grab the contents up until the fifth index.  Truncating the rest, you can find a lot of information on Microsoft Developer Network.

Comment: Even if you add the equal sign to the ping, it does not compile due to `string HostType = Console.WriteLine("hostname");`. I wonder why you answer on such a still unclear question...

Comment: @ThomasW. Well, that is assuming `HostType` is an actual class, not simply a `string` name.  Also assume that it is indeed the `enum` for it. The question is vague, but clear.  He wants to get the first for values for a `string`.  Ie, exactly like my answer and your comment.

Comment: When I send console.writeline("hostname");  the results in cmd is the servers host name is returned. The first 4 characters of the return value of sending "hostname" to the console is what i am needing to assign to a varable because the first 4 characters decided what type of server it is.